# 'At' Dnieper river or 'by' Dnieper river?

Tags: prepositions

If I'm on the walkway in / on / at Dnieper river, what is the right way to express it? (the right preposition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["By" or "at" the river and lake](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140476/by-or-at-the-river-and-lake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, there is usually a definite article ("the") before the name of the river.

In this sentence, the word "River" is usually optional.  If your audience does not know that the Dnieper is a river, include the word "River".  Also, if the name of the river (such as the "East River" along the eastern shore of Manhattan) could easily be confused with something that is not a river, include the word "River".  If present, the word "River" is usually capitalized (as part of the name of the river).

If the walkway is literally over the river:

> I'm on the walkway **over the** Dnieper.

If the walkway is on the shore, and more-or-less parallel to the river:

> I'm on the walkway **along the** Dnieper.

If the walkway is literally made out of the river (as in the frozen roads of northern Canada, or an ice-fishing lake):

> I'm on the walkway **on the** Dnieper.
>
> I'm in a boat on the Dnieper.

If you are emphasizing that you have just reached the river, or are crossing the river:

> I'm on the walkway **at the** Dnieper.

Comment: "On" is sometimes used to mean "on the banks of", as well as the more literal meaning you described. A scenic walkway might be described as "on the Dneiper", or a building, or even an entire town (e.g. UK city names like "Newcastle-on-Tyne").

Comment: ...Hmm I thought it was Necastle-***up***on-Tyne. (goes to Wikipedia to check)

Comment: ...(back from Wikipedia) Yep.  No dashes either.  I think you must have meant "Stratford-on-Avon" parliament district. The town is 'upon' as well.