# "By" or "at" the river and lake

Tags: prepositions

If we want to say "**near the river**" or "**near the lake**" which preposition is more accurate **by** or **at**?

I think when speaking about a river or lake **by** is better. Am I right? I mean when we are situated near by, somewhere close to the river or lake, near the bank of the river or on the beach by-side the lake.

Comment: "About a river" is too vague.  Are you going to cross the river, stroll along it, have a picnic? The choice of preposition will depend on such things.

Comment: "near the river" is fine. Why do you want to change it and then expect the same meaning (which is really unclear, by the way)?

Comment: Don't confuse the idea of being at a location, with being near it or by it.

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but you really can't boil it down so succinctly. You can be **at** a river, or **by** a river, and, in one sense, they mean the same thing, but in another sense, context can provide nuances that might make one preposition more apt than another. When it comes to prepositions, you just have to accept that there is often a lot of overlap, and no simple rule that will always tell you when one word might be better than the other.

Comment: @J.R. That's exactly the point. Now, here you are getting me right. I know approximately how prepositions work but I can see an overlap of **at** and **by** when speaking about close location to something. "**We were making a sandcastle right at the river**" or "**We were making a sandcastle right by the river**" to mean very close to the water? I think **at** is best. But if we were to speak about the beach further away from the water but close to it we would use **by** then? I mean **at** always means closer than **by** and **near** is something even further away from **by**.

Comment: @Sovereign - You can see the overlap, but what you are failing to see is that sometimes there is no "better" preposition to use. To say that "_at_ always means closer than _by_" misses the point. You are overthinking it. I might go so far as to say that "_at_ can often imply closer than _by_," but, if you said _at_ in your sandcastle sentence, no one is going to take out a measuring tape and scold you because you were too far away from the river to use _at_.

Comment: @J.R. I would like you to give a legible answer. I trust you can explain everything clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were now at the river, but it was too full of ice to be crossed safely.

We were strolling by the river, enjoying the sun and the light breeze.

We stood at the river's edge, and discussed whether to use live bait or artificial lures.

We sat by the river, listening to the ducks.

Comment: So actually both are quite fine when we mean **some short distance from the river/lake**?

Comment: They're not interchangeable. When you're *at* the river you have reached it, having traveled to get there. When you're *by* the river, you're next to it.

Comment: Doesn't "**at**" mean "*near*"? Consider, "*We are standing at the door*" and "*We are standing by the door*" - both mean "**near**", don't they?

Comment: @SovereignSun: You're near the right idea, but not at it yet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64776/discussion-on-answer-by-tomauo-by-or-at-the-river-and-lake).

Answer (score 3):

- After many days hiking, we were finally **at** the river. [**geographical location** just like at home, at school at the train station. To be at a place: location]
- We  hiked to the river but did not sit down in the grass **near** the river. We say some distance away. [near: close to a place or thing].
- We **sat** **by the river** on a bench and talked for hours. [by is alongside]

  Another example: Come sit down **by me.** Don't be shy.